# How to delete an archived artifact in jenkins?

Tags: build, hudson, jenkins, command-line-interface

1. I am using Jenkins with tomcat. I use jenkins cli from java class to create job and to build. **I want to  delete a archived artifact**. How to accomplish this?
2. Another question is, can we give a **specific name to the build** in jenkins (e.g) i want the build name like **(buildNumber + someName)**. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The artifacts for a build by default are located in: `[JENKINS_HOME]/jobs/[job_name]/builds/[$BUILD_ID]/archive/`, go there and delete it. It won't delete the link to the artifact from the build page, though. (If you are not sure where your JENKINS_HOME is, go to `http://[jenkins_server]/configure`, you'll see *Home directory* near the top of the page).

To change the display name of a build automatically try [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin).

To change the display name via CLI:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://[server]/ set-build-display-name [job_name] [build#] [new_name]
```

Comment: I am using hudson.cli with java. How to delete from hudson.cli methods. and also can we set name from build ?

Comment: @MuthuRaj I don't think there is a way to delete the artifacts of a specific build via the CLI.  I think you MUST go the file system and delete it manually.

Comment: I am using Jenkins ver. 2.32.2 and deleting the artifact from CLI removed it also from the build page.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone looking for another approach. If you are using the jenkins web interface and have administrator rights for it. You can run the following groovy script at "Manage Jenkins/Nodes/<master node>/Script Console".

```
def project = Jenkins.get().getItemByFullName('<your-project-id>')
def jobs = project.getAllJobs()

def total_size = 0

jobs.each{ job -> 
  def builds = job.getBuilds()
  builds.each{ build -> 
    def artifacts = build.artifacts
    artifacts.each{ artifact ->
      total_size += artifact.getFileSize()
      println "$artifact, ${artifact.getFileSize()}"
    }
    build.deleteArtifacts()
  } 
}

println "Total size: $total_size"
```

Kudos to [@perja12](https://gist.github.com/perja12/5bd255e45b1b2395dfd723500e93a77b) for creating the script.